# Sum property based on distinct values with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash, uniq

How can I make my data:

```
[
  {
    "a": {
      "b": 1,
      "c": "M"
    },
    "color": "white"
  },
  {
    "a": {
      "b": 10,
      "c": "M"
    },
    "color": "white"
  }
]
```

into this:

```
[
  {
    "a": {
      "b": 11,
      "c": "M"
    },
    "color": "white"
  }
]
```

I would like the `a.c` and `color` fields to be unique and `a.b` to combine.

I've tried using `_.uniq` but it's not working. I am using lodash 3.10.1.

Answer (score 2):

Not trivial, but here it goes:

```
// assuming the data is in `data`:
_.map(_.groupBy(data, x => [x.a.c, x.color]),
      x => _.tap(_.cloneDeep(x[0]), y => y.a.b = _.sum(x, z => z.a.b)))
```

First I group the objects by the composite value of `.a.c` and `.color`; in each group, I'll clone the first object to be the result, then overwrite its `.a.b` value with the sum of all `.a.b` values in the group.

EDIT: In wrapped syntax:

```
_(data).groupBy(x => [x.a.c, x.color]).map(x =>
  _.tap(_.cloneDeep(x[0]), y => y.a.b = _.sum(x, z => z.a.b))
).value()
```

Comment: Nice solution! Maybe we could use chaining to make it more readable, e.g. `_(data).groupBy(x => ...).map(x => ...).value()` :)

Comment: wow! the solution you gave is kinda hard to understand but I'll try. thank you. :)

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn: I agree, I am not that experienced with lodash and actually didn't know about wrapping. But I'd only wrap the front, because otherwise you end up in wrapping hell.

Comment: @Amadan agreed!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```js
var f = [{
  "a": {
    "b": 1,
    "c": "M"
  },
  "color": "white"
}, {
  "a": {
    "b": 10,
    "c": "M"
  },
  "color": "white"
}];

var res = _.reduce(f, (memo, o) => {
  var already = _.find(memo, o1 => o.a.c === o1.a.c || o.color === o1.color);
  return already ? (already.a.b += o.a.b, memo) : memo.concat(o);
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The idea here is to have an array (the result array) in which we have the unique objects. We then iterate over the original array: if the current object of the iteration is in the result array, we update the value and don't add anything. If it isn't we just add it.

Hope it helps.